# simplify boolean expression using consensus theorem

Tags: boolean-algebra

How to simplify this Boolean expression using consensus theories?

f(x,y,z) = xy + xy’z + y(x’+z) + y’z’

Comment: What do you mean by 'include theories'?

Comment: sorry my mistake

Comment: No problem! How exactly is your consensus theorem defined?